# Rock, Paper, Scissors- BlueJ crazy loop

Tags: java, loops, bluej

the following is my code for a rock, paper, scissors game in BlueJ. When I compile and the user enters an input, the computer immediately prints numerous outputs from playerWins(). The game ends when the user types "quit". Could someone help me so my screen won't be flooded? (and if there is any way to condense my code that would also be great).

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissors
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int wins = 0, losses = 0, ties = 0;
        boolean output;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("(R)ock, (P)aper, (S)cissors, or quit: ");
        String playerChoice = scan.nextLine();
        while (playerChoice.equals("quit") == false)
        {      
            playerChoice = playerChoice.toUpperCase();
            String computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
            if(playerChoice.equals(computerChoice) != true)
            {
                output = playerWins(playerChoice, computerChoice);
                if (output == true)
                {
                    wins++;
                }
                else if (output == false)
                {
                    losses++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ties++;
                System.out.println("Tie!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("QUIT");
        System.out.println("Wins: " + wins);
        System.out.println("Losses: " + losses);            
        System.out.println("Ties: " + ties); 
        scan.close();
    }
    public static String getComputerChoice()
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        int num = gen.nextInt(30) + 1;
        if (num % 3 == 2)
        {
            return "R";
        }
        else if (num % 3 == 1)
        {
            return "P";
        }
        else
        {
            return "S";
        }
    }
    public static boolean playerWins(String playerChoice, String computerChoice)
    {
        if (playerChoice.equals("R") == true)
        {
            if (computerChoice.equals("P") == true)
            {
                System.out.println("My Point! \nP beats R"); // Rock is beaten by paper
                return false;
            }
            else if (computerChoice.equals("S") == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Your Point! \nR beats S"); // Rock beats scissors
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (playerChoice.equals("P") == true)
        {
            if (computerChoice.equals("R") == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Your Point! \nP beats R"); //Paper beats rock
                return true;
            }
            else if (computerChoice.equals("S") == true)
            {
                System.out.println("My Point! \nS beats P"); //Paper is beaten by scissors
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (playerChoice.equals("S") == true)
        {
            if (computerChoice.equals("P") == true)
            {
                System.out.println("Your Point! \nS beats P"); //Scissor beats paper
                return true;
            }
            else if (computerChoice.equals("R") == true)
            {
                System.out.println("My Point! \nR beats S"); //Scissors is beaten by rock
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update `playerChoice` **in** the `while (playerChoice.equals("quit") == false)` *loop* in `main`. `playerChoice = scan.nextLine();` - otherwise, infinite loop without prompting for another choice.

Comment: What does *"... help me so my screen won't be flooded"* mean? Can you show some of the output?

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are the problem:

```
String playerChoice = scan.nextLine();
while (playerChoice.equals("quit") == false) {
```

You are reading one line and then checking that line over and over again. You need to read a new line **inside** the loop. The way you have it now, it is just trying to make the same move over and over infinite times.

Try:

```
String playerChoice = scan.nextLine();
while (playerChoice.equals("quit") == false) {

    //do all of the stuff that is already inside your loop

    playerChoice = scan.nextLine();
}
```

This will get user input again every time after processing the last input.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the user-input only once, that is before the loop:

```
String playerChoice = scan.nextLine();
```

One very nice method to solve that is the following:

```
String playerChoice;
while((playerChoice = scan.nextLine()).equals("quit") == false)
{
    //more code
}
```

What the above code does, is that `playerChoice` is set right before `.equals("quit")` is called. If you use this method you don't need one more line at the end of your loop to set `playerChoice` but just do that in the head of your loop.